# 4.7.14 Wordpress 4.7 problem with contribution form Birth Date

Tags: contribution-page, 4.7.14

CiviCRM version: 4.7.14
previous version: 4.7.12
Wordpress version: 4.7

My contribution form experience problem at the "Confirm contribution" page.
Upon pressing Confirm Contribution, user is brought back to the "Confirm Contribution" page with error "Please confirm birth date"
The error does not make sense as a birthdate is already in place.
And multiple tries of replacing birthdate with a different value did not help

A forced downgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.12 resolved the issue - a contribution can now go through.

Please advise! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi there there was an issue due to a change made in 4.7.14, It has been fixed in the up coming 4.7.15 version however I would suggest probably the better option is to upgrade and apply the following patch to your code base. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9530/